# Error while Rename file in ftp folder Java

Tags: java, apache, file, ftp, apache-commons-net

Following is my code to read the file and rename it afterwards. Im using `apache commons.net 3.0.1`.

```
client.connect(localhost);
boolean login = client.login("username", "password");
if(login){
    System.out.println("login successful");
    boolean chdir = client.changeWorkingDirectory("/home/folder1/child/");
    String url = client.printWorkingDirectory();   // EDIT
    FTPFile[] result = client.listFiles(url, filter);
    if (result != null && result.length > 0) {
        for (FTPFile aFile : result) {
            try{
                String filename = aFile.getName();
                InputStream is= client.retrieveFileStream(filename);
                br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));
                    while((line = br.readLine()) != null){
                        System.out.println("the line is"+line);
                     }
                }
                finally{
                    if(br!=null){
                        try{
                           br.close();
                           String oldFilename =url + "/" +aFile.getName();
                           String newFilename = "PRO"+aFile.getName();
                           boolean rename = client.rename(oldFilename, newFilename);
                            if(rename){
                                    System.out.println("renamed");
                            }   
                           else{
                                    System.out.println("Error in renaming");
                                }

                          }
```

The file deosn't get renamed and the program prints

> error in renaming files (cz boolean rename = false).

I have refereed to different examples. But all seems to show the same problem.
The file is picked after filter and read without any issues.

If anyone could point to what I'm doing wrong here, that'd be very helpful.

Here, the `url` is `String url = client.printWorkingDirectory();`

I have tried with both relative path and absolute path. And giving full path only to the `oldFilename` and just the filname to the `newFilename`. Both did not work.

**EDIT**

Before changing the directory, the url will be `/` which is root.
After changing the directory, the url will be `/home/folder1/child/`. This is the where the files exists.

Comment: Do you get any exception? If yes add the stacktrace.

Comment: @Jens There seems to be no exceptions.

Comment: Where this `error in renaming files (cz boolean rename = false).` is printing in your code?

Comment: @Jens It prints `"Error in renaming`. `cz boolean rename = false` was the assumption.

Comment: Does the rename work standalone (if you do not download the file first)?

Comment: @MartinPrikryl I read the file from shared folder (for just reading it doesnt have to download I suppose.), and I rename it there itself.

Comment: I ask if the `.rename` works if you remove the `.retrieveFileStream` block.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`InputStream retrieveFileStream(String remote)`:This method returns an `InputStream` which we can use to read bytes from the remote file. This method gives us more control on how to read and write the data. But there are two important points when using this method:

The method `completePendingCommand()` must be called afterward to finalize file transfer and check its return value to verify if the download is actually done successfully.

```
boolean success = ftpclient.completePendingCommand();
if (success){
        System.out.println("File #2 has been downloaded successfully.");
 }
```

We must close the InputStream explicitly.

`is.close();         //is  = InputStream`

[SOURCE](http://www.codejava.net/java-se/networking/ftp/java-ftp-file-download-tutorial-and-example)

Comment: Very helpful 